# Button in polymer element not calling on-click function

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

So I have some select elements and a button declared like this within a polymer-element

```html
...

<tr>
          <td>
            <select name="taskTypes" selectedIndex="{{selectedTaskTypeFilter}}"> 
              <option template repeat="{{key in taskTypeIndexes}}" value="{{key.toString()}}">
                {{taskTypes[key]}}
              </option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select name="taskStatusFilter" selectedIndex="{{selectedStatusFilter}}">
                <option template repeat="{{key in statusFilterIndexes}}" value="{{key.toString()}}">
                  {{statusFilters[key]}}
                </option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select name="targetLanguage" selectedIndex="{{selectedTargetFilter}}">
              <option template repeat="{{language in activeTargetLanguages}}" value="{{language.code}}">
                {{language.name}}
              </option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
<button value="Filter" class="btn btn-primary" on-click="{{filterStream}}">
  <i class="icon-refresh icon-white"></i> {{localisation.getTranslation("index_filter_task_stream")}}
</button>

...
```

(Inb4 someone bemoans use of tables; it's not my code originally and I kind of would like to replace them but it's not top priority.)

This is the `filterStream()` function the button is supposed to call but it seems not to get called at all as is evident from the output of the print statement not showing up.

```dart
void filterStream()
  {
    print("Entered filterStream");
    filter = "";
    if (isFiltered) {
      filteredTasks.clear();
      filteredTasks.addAll(filteredTasksBackup);
    }

    if (filteredTasksBackup.length == 0) {
      UserDao.getUserTasks(userid, taskCount)
        .then((List<Task> userTasks) {
          filteredTasks = userTasks;
          filteredTasksBackup = userTasks;
          isFiltered = true;
      });
    }

    if (selectedTaskTypeFilter > 0) {
      //Remove all tasks but those of the selected type
      filteredTasks.removeWhere((task) => task.taskType != selectedTaskTypeFilter);
    }

    if (selectedStatusFilter > 0) {
      //Remove all tasks but those with the selected status
      //The + 2 is to adjust the values so that they match correctly; task status 3 and 4 are in progress and
      //complete, respectively, but on the UI filter they are the 2nd and 3rd options (hence index 1 and 2).
      filteredTasks.removeWhere((task) => task.taskStatus != selectedStatusFilter + 2);
    }
    goToFirstPage();
  }
```

The full ClaimedTaskStream.dart file can be found [here](https://github.com/TheRosettaFoundation/SOLAS-Match/blob/claimedTasksFilter/ui/dart/web/Routes/Users/ClaimedTasksStream.dart#L371) if it helps. Also, as it may be relevant, I should mention  I am running the code as JS compiled by dart2js.

Answer (score 0):

The method needs to have three arguments Event, detail,  and target

```
filterStream(MouseEvent e, detail, Element target)  {   }
```

Comment: The arguments are not required. At least in previous versions.

Comment: I should have mentioned also, I copied this from existing code in the codebase, where the on-click function has no args just like here, and that one works.

Comment: This is new to me, a few weeks ago this still only worked when the method had exactly these parameters and I haven't heared of any changes. I will of course try this out ASAP but I have no computer available for a few days.

Comment: Was lightdom also used where you copied the code from. I have never used it myself but I remember that it was reported occassionally that it causes problems with events (don't remember any details though)

Comment: Yes in fact it is...I was discussing the issue with a former coworker who developed this code and he pointed out the fact that the element uses lightdom is likely the issue. He said he had problems in development in the past that led him to use it but it may well be the case the those problems are a thing of the past. I will need to check this out later.